# 4 digit password type view: number and cursor control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, interface-builder

First posting to Stackoverflow, but have been searching for answers for sometime now.
Learning Objective-C & XCode and have been creating simple projects.
Currently, I wanted to attempt a screen where user will enter in a 4 digit password code, where each individual digit in seperate text fields.
1)  How to make cursor be in first text field, causing keyboard to come up automatically when app is started

2)  How to make the text field only accept one digit.  Can you do this in interface builder, in the attributes for the text field?  Or do you have to do that programmatically?

3)  How to make cursor jump to next text field after previous one is filled.  Will this happen automatically when question #2 is done?

Would appreciate any help... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here you go
1. You must create 4 UITextFields in the IB say textField1, textField2, textField3, textField4. and call [textField1 becomesFirstResponder]; this will make the cursor in your textfield1.

2.To make textfield accept only one digit, you will have to do this

```
    -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    textField.text  =   string;
    if ([string length] > 0) {
    if ([textField isEqual:textField1]) {
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];

    }else if([textField isEqual:textField2]) {

        [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];

    }else if([textField isEqual:textField3]) {

        [textField4 becomeFirstResponder];

    }else if([textField isEqual:textField4]) {

        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
return FALSE;
```

}

you will have to do this programmatically.

3.same as ans2.

Comment: Perfect!  I had found out about becomeFirstRepsonder before you posted.  But you finished up my question 2 & 3.  Got it to work!  Thanks!

Comment: thats great, if u got your answers, please put make this post answered.

Answer (score 1):

Create a hidden uitextfield that you are actually typing into. Then create four 'seen' uitextfields and add a bullet character into each one as the user types into the hidden field.

This is the easiest way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This solution was surprisingly hard to find.